# What is the difference between a semi-permeable membrane and a selectively permeable membrane?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

What is the difference between a semi-permeable membrane and a selectively permeable membrane in cell biology? Is a selectively permeable membrane a type of semi-permeable membrane? Please help.

I think the semi-permeable membrane allows passage to only solvent molecules while a selectively permeable membrane permits the movement of solvent molecules along with some selected solutes. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Welcome. I can understand your confusion, but there is a *lot* online about this. Using your exact phrasing, the top Google hits explained the difference. What do you understand about each type of membrane? (Asking to understand exactly the point where your confusion starts.) What were your search terms? If English is your first language, how do you understand *semi* and *selective* in general? Please click the edit button to include details and a quote from one of your sources. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite. Semi-permeable membranes permit diffusion of anything limited only by size. Anything bigger than the pore size can't pass (there are different pore sizes in different membranes.) Selectively permeable membranes allow *certain select molecules/substances* to pass and nothing else, independent of size. They are made to allow a particular substance to diffuse through. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.